# c++: Dynamically choose which subclass to create

Tags: c++, class, dynamic, derived

I am new to c++ and i have a question.

Lets say we have a base class Base and two derived classes, Derived1 and Derived2.
f.e. Derived1 has a constructor taking a integer and Derived2 a constructor taking a boolean.

Is it possible to determine at run time (or at compile time) which of those two subclasses to create and assign it to the Base class.

Something like this:
Base b = ???(value), where value is of type integer or boolean.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're used to Java, remember that in C++, `Base b` declares an *object*, not a reference to an object. If you assign a derived object to a base object, then it will be sliced (assuming it even compiles). For dynamic polymorphism in C++, you need to use pointers as in AraK's answer.

Comment: What do your classes do? It might make more sense to use a templated derivate, i.e. something like `Derived<int> d(someInt);`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want [Factory Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_pattern).

Answer (score 8):

Write two overloads of a function called `createMyBlaBla`. One accepting `int`, and the other accepting `bool`. Everyone returns the desired derived class type. e.g.:

```
Base* create(int n)
{
    return new Derived1(n);
}
Base* create(bool b)
{
    return new Derived2(b);
}
....
Base* b1 = create(10);    // Derived1
Base* b2 = create(false); // Derived2
```

People call this the factory pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really think this is possible the way you want it to be,
polymorphism in C++ just doesn't work like this.

If I understood well, you want a variable declared as Base decides,
depending on the parameter type, whether it is going to be Derived1 or
Derived2, all without using the Factory pattern.

The reason why this is not possible is that, the `Base`
class is not really aware of the existence of its `Derived`
classes nor you can declare a stack variable and make it "behave" as a derived class. However, I can suggest a work-around but then again, this
doesn't satisfy all the expectations of the real class hierarchy you
want (if you really want it that way_:

```
class Facade{

public:
    Facade(int foo) : b(new Derived1(foo)){}

    Facade(bool foo) : b(new Derived2(foo)){}

    Base Value()
    {
        return *b;
    }

private:
    Base* b;

};
```

And then you can do something like:

```
Facade foo(10);
Facade bar(true);

int x = (reinterpret_cast<Derived1*>(foo.Value())) -> val;
bool y = (reinterpret_cast<Derived2*>(bar.Value())) -> val;
```

Comment: By the way, reinterpret_cast is unsafe... You'd be better off using dynamic_cast instead.

Comment: Downcast should use static_cast if the caller is certain that the runtime type actually is the specified derived type, dynamic_cast otherwise (and check for null). You can only dynamic_cast classes with a virtual function, so make sure there is one (probably the destructor will be virtual, if you're messing with pointers and polymorphism).